# Deploying Django to Elastic Beanstalk, /opt/python does not exist

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm completely lost & have been trying to fix the same issue for the past 4-5 days while deploying my django app.

The issue is as follows.

My migration command is failing, the migrate config file is as follows

```
container_commands:

01_migrate:

command: "python3 manage.py migrate"

leader_only: true



option_settings:

aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: djangomicroblog.settings
```

I've also tried changing the command to a number of different things, including:

```
command: "python manage.py migrate"

command: "django-admin.py migrate"

command: "/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3 manage.py migrate"
```

Different commands give me different errors, python manage.py migrate reports:

```
2020-06-21 13:15:48,639 P8373 [INFO] File "manage.py", line 16

2020-06-21 13:15:48,639 P8373 [INFO] ) from exc

2020-06-21 13:15:48,639 P8373 [INFO] ^

2020-06-21 13:15:48,640 P8373 [INFO] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I assume this is because it's trying to execute with python2

Python3 manage.py migrate reports:

```
2020-06-21 13:12:37,445 P8066 [INFO] Traceback (most recent call last):

2020-06-21 13:12:37,445 P8066 [INFO] File "manage.py", line 10, in main

2020-06-21 13:12:37,445 P8066 [INFO] from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

2020-06-21 13:12:37,445 P8066 [INFO] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

2020-06-21 13:12:37,445 P8066 [INFO]

2020-06-21 13:12:37,445 P8066 [INFO] The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

2020-06-21 13:12:37,445 P8066 [INFO]

2020-06-21 13:12:37,445 P8066 [INFO] Traceback (most recent call last):

2020-06-21 13:12:37,445 P8066 [INFO] File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>

2020-06-21 13:12:37,445 P8066 [INFO] main()

2020-06-21 13:12:37,445 P8066 [INFO] File "manage.py", line 16, in main

2020-06-21 13:12:37,445 P8066 [INFO] ) from exc

2020-06-21 13:12:37,446 P8066 [INFO] ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

So i've been trying to find the virtual environment which the internet says should be in /opt/python/ (which i'm accessing through ssh and sudo su), but this directory just does not exist

My directory structure is as follows:

[image: directory structure on local device]

The only idea I have now is that my app being written in python 3.8 & therefore the requirements.txt being from 3.8 causing incompatibilities? But i've no idea how to fix this if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work is most likely because you are using EB environment for `Amazon Linux 2`, while your **application** has been developed for `Amazon Linux 1`.

Thus it is looking for python in the **wrong location**. To fix that ensure that you are creating python environment for `Amazon Linux 1`, not `Amazon Linux 2`.

There are many differences between AL1 and AL2, which make them **incompatible**.

Comment: Thank you so much! turns out my application had a mix of AL1 and AL2 settings, but the env was running on AL2. Reverted some of the config in the application to AL1 settings, and am now using an AL2 env with python 3.6 & it's up and running! 

None of the tutorials / resources I'd looked at mentioned I had to use AL1 (i guess because it's new?), so i assumed I'd just want to use the newest python version when creating the env (which happened to be 3.7 AL2).

Comment: Done :) have a great day

Comment: @BillieM AL2 is very new, thus most tutorials and guides out there will be about AL1.